# Showing density of vector layer with polygons inside boundaries of another in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, layers, overlapping-features, density

In QGIS I've got one layer showing local authority boundaries across the country (UK), and another which shows polygons of particular sites across the whole country.

Can I show the density of the sites (by number of sites) within each of the local authority boundaries? I'm sure I've done this before but I'm having to relearn and just can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: This topic could be helpful: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/228442/count-polygons-in-polygons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a categorized styling with the expression: `array_length(overlay_intersects('sites', "namn1"))`

Replace 'sites' with the name of your layer to count, and namn1 with the name of some attribute in your sites layer.

The expression will return the number of overlapping sites for each boundary polygon.
[image]

Comment: Many many thanks! I'm unbelievably grateful. A whole new world has opened up... ❤️